# c# list.add() overwrite the object at position 0

Tags: c#, winforms

i am updating my question to this 
i created new class  Student

```
class Student
    {

        private string _firstName;
        private string _lastName;
        private int _exam1;
        private int _exam2;
        private int _exam3;
        private int _finalExam;


        // First Name Property
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { _firstName = value; }
        }

        //Last Name Property
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { _lastName = value; }
        }

        //Exam 1 Property
        public int Exam1
        {
            get { return _exam1; }
            set { _exam1 = value; }
        }

        // Exam 2 Property
        public int Exam2
        {
            get { return _exam2; }
            set { _exam2 = value; }
        }

        //Exam 3 Property
        public int Exam3
        {
            get { return _exam3; }
            set { _exam3 = value; }
        }

        //Final Exam Property
        public int FinalExam
        {
            get { return _finalExam; }
            set { _finalExam = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my add new student form class with one method to add new student

```
public class AddStudent : Form
    {

        StudentForm stu = null;

        public AddStudent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            stu = new StudentForm();
            stu.Show();

        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // split the name into first and last name
            string[] name = txtName.Text.Split(',');
            Student std = new Student();
            std.FirstName = name[0];
            std.LastName = name[1];
            std.Exam1 = Int32.Parse(txtExam1.Text);
            std.Exam2 = Int32.Parse(txtExam2.Text);
            std.Exam3 = Int32.Parse(txtExam3.Text);
            std.FinalExam = Int32.Parse(txtFinal.Text);
            stu.addItem(std);
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my main form it has listbox to display list of students

```
public  class StudentForm : Form
    {            
        public StudentForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

        public void addItem(Student std)
        {

            students.Add(std);
            // it always show me 1 item in list
            MessageBox.Show(students.Count.ToString());

        }
}
```

Comment: This part seems very odd - `std.addItem(std);` - you're adding a form item to itself?  I suspect that the reason you see the first item overwritten is because you're creating a _new_ `Student` each time but your class structure makes it very confusing.

Comment: @DStanley no it makes perfect sense. The OP has a form that contains a list of that form and the OP creates a new instance of it and than adds it self to the list. The purpose of this is as clear as that last sentence.

Comment: Actually i am learning c# can you please give my idea ?

Comment: @SaqibSaqib What does the `Student` UI screen have ? Is it your entry point ? Or `AddStudent` is your first screen ?

Comment: A "fix" of sorts is to just make your `students` list `static`. But it doesn't make sense for the `Student` class to contain a list of all students, that should be at a higher level, and that higher level should be the one to add them too (a student doesn't need to know about callers and that they might want them added to a list or not).

Comment: it has One listBox to show list of students and one menu item to add new student to list

Answer (score 3):

Here's how your code is progressing, with comments added and irrelevant code removed:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    // create a _new_ Student form
    Student std = new Student();

    ...

    // Add the student form to itself (huh?)
    std.addItem(std);

    // hide this form
    this.Hide();

    // show the new form
    std.Show();
}
```

So you are always showing a new form with one item - the one that was just created.

Comment: give me idea please

Comment: I would have just one _form_ object and multiple _data_ objects.  It looks like you're using one class (`Student`) to represent both a form and the data, which is making for a confusing program.  Until that is fixed I can;t clearly see how to get the program to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's cause in your `btnSubmit_Click` every time you are creating a new instance of the form `Student` and calling the `addItem()` method.

You rather move this field to a separate class like

```
public class Data
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    private int _exam1;
    private int _exam2;
    private int _exam3;
    private int _finalExam;
}
```

have the form instance created in the start up like

```
public partial class AddStudent : Form
    {

Student stu = null;
public AddStudent()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    stu = new Student();
    stu.Show();
}
```

Change the list in Form1

```
public List<Data> students = new List<Data>();
```

In button click just add the `Data` instance like

```
   private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // split the name into first and last name
        string[] name = txtName.Text.Split(',');
        Data std = new Data();
        std.FirstName = name[0];
        std.LastName = name[1];
        std.Exam1 = Int32.Parse(txtExam1.Text);
        std.Exam2= Int32.Parse(txtExam2.Text);
        std.Exam3 = Int32.Parse(txtExam3.Text);
        std.FinalExam = Int32.Parse(txtFinal.Text);
        stu.addItem(std);
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: could you please give me any idea?

Comment: i did this but same issue

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're creating the `Student` form each time using this line:

```
Student std = new Student();
```

So every time you're clicking submit, you're creating a new Student form which creates a new empty `public List<Student>`

You need to seperate your model (`Student`) from your UI (`StudentForm`) and (`AddStudentForm`):

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { set; get; }
    private string LastName { set; get; }
    private int Exam1 { set; get; }
    private int Exam2 { set; get; }
    private int Exam3 { set; get; }
    private int FinalExam { set; get; }
}
```

You don't need to create a new `StudentForm` each time you add a `Student`. Instead, you can have one `StudentForm` and use `ShowDialog()` when navigating to the Addition Screen, this you go back to the same instance of `StudentForm`.

Comment: any idea to fix this issue ?

Comment: @SaqibSaqib What does the `Student` UI screen have ? Is it your entry point ? Or `AddStudent` is your first screen ?

Comment: it has One listBox to show list of students and one menu item to add new student to list

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the `Class Student` instantiation out of the event - `btnSubmit_Click event
Student std = new Student();`